# BeautifulSoup.select classname not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find tags by CSS class, using BeautifulSoup.
Read [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) and tried different ways but the below code returns `new_elem   : []`.
Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://solanamonkeysclub.com/#/#mint"

response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
new_elems = str(soup.select('.ant-card-body'))
print(f'{"new_elem":10} : {new_elems}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the url is dynamic,I use selenium with bs4 and getting the follwing output:

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://solanamonkeysclub.com/#/#mint"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(8)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
new_elems = soup.select('.ant-card-body')
for new_elem in new_elems:
    print(f'{"new_elem":10} : {new_elem.text}')
```

OUTPUT:

```
new_elem   : 0
new_elem   : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the output at all?  You should bring up this page in a browser and do a "view source", or do `print(response.text)` after you fetch it.  The page as delivered contains no HTML elements.  The entire page is built dynamically using Javascript.

You will need do use something like `Selenium` to scrape it.